# I am getting an __initerror

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to put a question-banner (as an MDGridLayout) in a specific place on my screen so that questions will be loaded through my FireBase.

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/GOAT/main.py", line 124, in <module>
     NavDrawerAndScreenManagerApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 944, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/GOAT/main.py", line 103, in on_start
     Q = QuestionBanner(side_i_1=question['side_i_1'], side_n_1=question['side_n_1'])
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\questionsbanner.py", line 10, in __init__
     super(QuestionBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\gridlayout.py", line 256, in __init__
     super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\backgroundcolorbehavior.py", line 150, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\GOAT\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Here is my main.py relevant code (the last two lines I believe are the source for the error as if I comment (#) them out, the app runs):

```
    my_questions_grid = self.root.ids['my_questions_grid']
    questions = data['questions']
    # iterate through the firebase dictionaries
    for question_num, question in questions.items():
        # populate Home screen
        Q = QuestionBanner(side_i_1=question['side_i_1'], side_n_1=question['side_n_1'])
        my_questions_grid.add_widget(Q)
```

This is my QuestionsBanner file.py relevant code:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # Up - question text

    # Left side
    left = MDFloatLayout()
    left_image = Image(source='photos/' + kwargs['side_i_1'], size_hint=(1, 0.8), pos_hint={'top': 1, 'left': 1})
    left_label = MDLabel(text=kwargs['side_n_1'], size_hint=(1, 0.2), pos_hint={'top': 0.2, 'left': 1})
    left.add_widget(left_image)
    left.add_widget(left_label)

    self.add_widget(left)
```

Here is the relevant main.kv code:

```
MDTabs:
    pos_hint: {'top': .5, 'left': 1}
    size_hint: 1, .4
    id: android_tabs
    on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
    Tab:
        text: "My Questions"
        MDGridLayout:
            id: my_questions_grid
```

Thank you to anyone who can shed some light over this!

Comment: How can we know what `super(QuestionBanner, self)` is if you don't show it? Also, we don't even know for sure what line caused the error, as you didn't include the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Hey thank you, I added the complete traceback - what else do you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__()` of the `QuestionBanner` class, you are calling:

```
super(QuestionBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

which is passing all your `kwargs` to the super `__init__()` method, and that super `__init__()` does not understand your `kwargs` that you pass in the constructor:

```
Q = QuestionBanner(side_i_1=question['side_i_1'], side_n_1=question['side_n_1'])
```

So those args get passed through similar `super` calls till it gets to the `object` `__init__()` which does not accept any `kwargs`, so it raises an `Exception`. The fix is to get your `__init__()` for `QuestionBanner` to remove those `kwargs` before you call `super`. One simple way to do that is to just add properties for the `kwargs` like this:

```
class QuestionBanner(MDGridLayout):
    side_i_1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    side_n_1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Up - question text

        # Left side
        left = MDFloatLayout()
        left_image = Image(source='photos/' + kwargs['side_i_1'], size_hint=(1, 0.8), pos_hint={'top': 1, 'left': 1})
        left_label = MDLabel(text=kwargs['side_n_1'], size_hint=(1, 0.2), pos_hint={'top': 0.2, 'left': 1})
        left.add_widget(left_image)
        left.add_widget(left_label)

        self.add_widget(left)
```

This code may be incorrect, since you haven't provided us with all the relevant code, but defining some type of `Properties` with the required names will automatically set the `Properties` and remove those `kwargs` before the `super` call.